# How to enable StatsD in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, datadog, micrometer, statsd, spring-micrometer

I have Spring Boot 2.5.2 and I am trying to send StatsD metrics to Datadog. However, that didn't work for me. So I wrote a single python script to check if my application is sending any data or not.

application.properties

```
management.metrics.export.statsd.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.statsd.host=localhost
management.metrics.export.statsd.port=8125
```

Python script

```
from socket import *
serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind((serverName, serverPort))
print("Server is ready.")


while True:
    msg, clientAddr = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
    word = msg.decode()
    print(word)
    msg = ''
    serverSocket.sendto(msg.encode(), clientAddr)
```

I tested this script with the following command:

```
$ echo "foo:1|c" | nc -u -w0 127.0.0.1 12000
```

and it was logged by the script.

I changed `management.metrics.export.statsd.port` to 12000, but nothing was being sent. Is there a way to diagnose this?

Comment: Did you add the appropriate dependencies?

Comment: I only have `spring-boot-starter-actuator`. Do I need any other dependency?

Comment: Yes. `micrometer-registry-statsd` at the very least.